# Webpage has a redirect loop www to non-www

Tags: linux, .htaccess, debian

I installed lamp on debian 7 but i need a non-www url now my website always add www. before

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.example.com (the same issu with example.com)
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/site/www
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/site/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I test with htaccess too but browser give me loop

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why apache add www ? Its new configuration i have just enable one site.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is a cache problem. Try clearing your cache to see if it works. As a recommendation, I would make `ServerName` `example.com` and `ServerAlias` `*.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks but not work i changed my `ServerAlias` restart apache, clear cache but always  he redirect me to www (with other browser its same) its possible this redirection is from my registra  godaddy ? But im use cloudflare for dns...

Comment: I think you should ensure that `mod_rewrite` is turned on. I'm assuming it's turned off because if something is redirecting to the `www.` version, there should be a redirect loop because your `.htaccess` file strips the `www.`.

Comment: What do you have installed on your server? Could a framework be causing the redirect instead? I see you are using permanent redirects for testing. Don't do this, as mistakes you have made previously are cached and cause strange, non-reproducible behaviour. Your rewriterule does not cause this non-www to www-redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the domain `example.com` actually resolves via DNS
(and not just `www.example.com`)

Modern browsers (and not-so-modern browsers as well) will try to auto-correct the domain if they cannot resolve it.

Among other things this means that they will try to prepend `www.` to the domain-name.

Comment: In my registra or virtual host ? Actualy in godaddy i have 2 hostname and 1 subdomaine (1: `@  my:ip:v6 AAAA`, 2: `www   example.com  CNAME`, and subdomaine is `mx for mail.example.com`)